# Symbolic Links in Production Server?

Tags: iis, symlink

We have implemented an API that is currently in production, and we would like to use that same API in another subdomain witouth having to download any SVN files but instead to use the original folder, I have done this using a Symbolic Link, but the question is that is it safe to use a Symbolic Link, does it have any performance issues or something I may not be considering? or can I use copy and paste the same folder on any change.